# Python, making a POST request passing file from a S3 location

Tags: python, rest, amazon-s3, http-post

I am trying to implement a simple scenario where i read a binary file from an S3 bucket and send tha to a RESTFUL service via POST data.

From another post I found the documentation to make a complex POST:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
>>> r.text
{
  ...
  "files": {
    "file": "<censored...binary...data>"
  },
  ...
}
```

I don't know if and how to pass my S3 file into the files variable.

Comment: Do you have code to load your S3 bucket yet? You'd need to get a file-like object from that, *or* a bytestring.

Comment: Hi Martijin, not yet. I am actually using IBM object storage, and I found an example: 
https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/python
integrating this to the previous one is another challenge...

Comment: `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`, `obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)`, `data = obj.get()['Body'].read()` gives you a bytestring you can post directly, use it instead of an open file object.